# concat/uglify js files using grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following folder structure

```
root
    src
        ui
            ui1
                js
                    ui.js
                page1
                    page.js
                page2
                    page.js
            ui2
                js
                    ui.js
                page1
                    page.js
                page2
                    page.js
                page3
                    page.js
    css
    js
    ui
```

Is it possible to run grunt uglify on this to achieve the following: concatenate all js files from each `ui[x]` folder from `root/src/` into the `root/ui/` folder keeping the path structure intact?

I would like to end up with

```
root
    src
        ui
            ui1
                js
                    ui.js
                page1
                    page.js
                page2
                    page.js
            ui2
                js
                    ui.js
                page1
                    page.js
                page2
                    page.js
                page3
                    page.js
    css
    js
    ui
            ui1
                ui.min.js
            ui2
                ui.min.js
```

My problem is that `ui[x]` and `page[x]` folders will be added later so I would need to make this dynamic.
What I was able to achieve is either concatenate all files without keeping the path or keep the path, uglify but not concatenate. Any help is appreciated.

```
files: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src/ui/',
    src: '**/*',
    dest: 'ui/'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to implement a [rename function](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#the-rename-property). The purpose of this function is to give you finer control over src/dest mappings when your use-case cannot be satisfied by the default configurations. The `rename` function will be called for each source file that matches your `src` pattern and will allow you to define the logic that determines the destination file.

This will work even if we map multiple source files to a single destination file. The docs say:

> If multiple matched src paths are renamed to an identical destination (i.e. if two different files get renamed to the same file), each output will be added to an array of sources for it.

Our objective, starting from the `root/src/ui/` directory, is to gather every filepath ending in ".js" and, for each, produce a destination filepath that is the first directory name plus "/ui.min.js". For example, `ui1/js/ui.js` would map to `ui1/ui.min.js` and `ui2/page3/page.js` would map to `ui2/ui.min.js`.

With the logic established, the implementation of our `rename` function is fairly trivial. Our Gruntfile would look like the following:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: {
            dist: ['root/ui']
        },

        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'root/src/ui/',
                        src: ['**/*.js'],
                        dest: 'root/ui/',
                        rename: function (dest, src) {
                            return dest + src.substring(0, src.indexOf('/') + 1) + 'ui.min.js';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'uglify']);

};
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you, didn't know about the rename function, should have read the docs carefully. Can you please explain the "clean" task, never used it before.

Comment: @slash197: I am using the grunt-contrib-clean task to delete the contents of the dist folder (`root/ui`) before we build. I do this just to make sure we are starting fresh. If you were to delete your `src/ui/ui2` folder, this would ensure that `root/ui/ui2` got removed.